# Internet breaks when there is heavy data traffic

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

I'm using wifi connection and my connection was working fine. But recently, after I add a raspberry pi device to the network, I start to notice something weird on my laptop. The internet will break when I install something, or when using ssh or scp command in the terminal. sometime it will break while browsing. The internet would work again when I enable and disable the airplane mode.

I checked the connection on my other laptop and it was fine. Both laptops are using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and both have similar network setting. I would like to add that I didn't change my router setting.

When using phone data to connect to the internet, the connection would be fine and the problem would not occurs. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would question the Rpi configuration. Is it using DHCP or did you hardcode its IP address? It could be stealing your adress or the router's.... On your machine, do `arp -a` when things work and compare to the same when they don't. Is the MAC address of your router the same?

Comment: There are too many questions here for this to be an snswer.

Comment: What is the pi doing? Is it accessible from the internet?

Comment: Hi @xenoid. When doing `arp -a` in the two cases, the output will be the same. However, when the network is not working, the output will take around 1 minute to show up. Regarding the Rpi, it uses a static IP address. 

The router MAC address is the same in all devices `192.168.0.1`

Comment: Hi @ pLumo! Yes, it does. It uses DAKboard system.

Comment: What you mean. How is accesible? Maybe you forward port 22 to the pi ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I got your point. It uses the internet through wifi. it has this ip address `192.168.0.45/24`

Comment: I mean if it is accessible **from** the internet ...

Comment: *Regarding the Rpi, it uses a static IP address* And you checked it is outside of the range used for DHCP?

Comment: I noticed that I can access the Rpi thought ssh only if the other device is connected to the same router. otherwise, I would not be able to connect.

Comment: 192.168.0.45/24? Shouldn't that be 192.168.0.45/32?

Comment: The current range of DHCPv4 seems to be: `Starting local address = 192.168.0.10`
and `Number of CPEs = 245` and `Lease time = 3600 seconds`

Comment: all other devices in the network have the `.../24` in their IP address.

Comment: All devices seem to be on that range.

Comment: Yes, but DHCP avoid conflicts between the addresses it assigns. If the Rpi address is static, DHCP doesn't know about it and may assign that address to another device. So either the Rpi used DHCP or you give it an address outside of the DHCP range. It should be possible to tell your router to restrict the DHCP range to a subset of your subnet (say, the 128 first) and give the Rpi an address in the other half....

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for the suggestion. I gave the Rpi a reserved IP address in DHCP and that seems to solve the issue. The Rpi had a static IP but the router might have no information about that. Can you please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Done, with some more explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that your Rpi has a static address, and it likely shares the network with other devices that use addresses dynamically assigned by the DHCP server (your router).

The DHCP server avoids conflicts between the addresses it assigns. But if the Rpi address is static, DHCP doesn't know about it and may assign that address to another device, so two devices are using the same IP address. Thing becomes a bit random at that point, depending on what each devices has in its arp cache.

So either make the Rpi acquire its address via DHCP(*) or give it an address outside of the DHCP range. It should be possible to tell your router to restrict the DHCP range to a subset of your subnet (say, the 128 first) and give the Rpi an address in the other half...

(*) Yes the address is not known in advance, but in practice the DHCP devices get a "lease" on their address, so unless you have very many devices connecting to your network, a given device will always get the same address, and you can still hardcode the Rpi address. There are also ways to dynamically discover the address of connected devices (WINS).